# Simultaneously raising and lowering indices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

Let $U$ be a four-vector and $\nabla$ denote the covariant derivative in the Levi-Civita connection. Is it always true that $$\left(\nabla_{\mu}U^{\nu}\right)U_{\nu}=\left(\nabla_{\mu}U_{\nu}\right)U^{\nu}~?$$

I have tried expanding the covariant derivative out. On the LHS you will get a positive Christoffel symbol, whereas on the RHS, you will get a negative one. This makes me think it is not true, but I would appreciate if somebody could explain this.

Comment: It is always true, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\nabla_{\mu}U_{\nu}\right)U^{\nu}&=\left[\nabla_{\mu}(g_{\nu\sigma}U^\sigma)\right]U^{\nu}\\&=\left(\nabla_{\mu}g_{\nu\sigma}\right)U^\sigma U^{\nu}+\left(\nabla_{\mu}U^\sigma\right)g_{\nu\sigma} U^{\nu}
\\&=0+\left(\nabla_{\mu}U^\sigma\right)U_\sigma\\&=
\left(\nabla_{\mu}U^{\nu}\right)U_{\nu}\end{align*}$$